# Why ERC-20 interface uses uint256 while Uniswap router uint?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap

ERC-20 token interface functions like `balanceOf`, `allowance` returns an `uint256`. While the functions of the Uniswap router interface take `uint` for the token amounts and returns `uint[]` in some cases.

My question is, why these interfaces are using different integer types for token related functions? For instance I buy some tokens with `swapExactETHForTokens` which returns an `uint[]`, then I call `balanceOf` on the contract of the purchased token and that returns an `uint256`. How will be `uint256` from `uint`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple `uint` and `int` are similar to `uint256` and `int256`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

uint is an alias for uint256. A good example contract that focuses on primitives
https://solidity-by-example.org/primitives